# Iphone App Local Storage To Create App ID On App Install

Tags: ios, cordova, local-storage

I need to add one piece of functionality which relates to local storage when the app loads the first time after its downloaded from the app store. I have developed my app using only using jquerymobile and cordova

What I need  is some code to achieve the following

Once the app is downloaded onto the iphone / ipad and its opened the app needs to check for the presence of a local storage value called AppID

If appID value does not exist in local storage the app needs to generate a random AppID that is in the following format xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx where the x values can be numbers or characters

The randomly generated AppId then needs to be placed in local storage so that it remains in place even after the iphone is rebooted and is only deleted if the app is deleted from the phone.

On the home page of the App I then need to have the AppID value retrieved from local storage displayed

If anyone can directly me to sample code that achieves the above or has already written code that achieves the above i would be very greatful

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in delegate class method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] intForKey:@"appID"]==0)
{
    //first time launch
    //generate an appID and save
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:app_id forKey:@"appID"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
else
{
    //has launched before or app_id has been saved before, retrieve app_id
    app_id=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] intForKey:@"appID"]

}
```

Comment: I have tried sending an email to the id you mentioned but it is giving some error. You can contact me on khawar_ali89@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know localStorage in not persistent with ios. ios can delete localStorage whenever it needs memory. You can just use a database like webSQL to save your app_id and check at the beginning of the app that it is set or not and if set,what it's value.